# unable to copy folders with same permission

Tags: copy

I want to copy `/var/lib` with same permissions of all files and folders.

some articles says `cp -rp /var/lib/      /var/libnew/`

and some says use `rsync -aX /var/lib     /var/libnew/`

explain please which one is better as most important thing in which All permissions should be same 100 percent.

Answer (score 1):

Both articles are correct and does what you want.

I prefer using `rsync -avh --progress <source>/ <destination>` (in your case: `rsync -avh --progress /var/lib/ /varlibnew`) for the progress bar of the copying, you can also add `-u` if you want to update files in `destination`, if they are newer.

With rsync, mind that trailing `/` are of importance, if both source and destination have trailing `/`:s, then the destination goes one level deeper.

Comment: ok thanks this is working fine for me with progress status.